React flow, hiding edge based level
So i am plotting a graph and using level to determine the x- position of graph
sample node data:
{
   id: "6661a4f030b3873fb1928f26",
   level: 0,
   displayName: "test-login",
   properties: {
     logoId: "",
   },
},

sample edge data :
 {
sourceId: "6661a4f030b3873fb1928f26",
        targetId: "6661a4f230b3873fb1928f37",
        properties: {
          permission: "",
        },
}


What i want to achieve is that, suppose i have 3 nodes, A, B, C and they are connected by edges, A->B , B->C now if i hide level 1 (Node B), a new edge should be created namely, A->C,
My function:

interface Node {
  id: string;
  level: number;
}

interface Edge {
  sourceId: string;
  targetId: string;
  properties?: Record<string, any>; // Adjust the type according to your properties structure
}

interface Visibility {
  group: boolean;
  role: boolean;
}

export const filterNodesAndCreateEdges = (
  nodes: Node[],
  edges: Edge[],
  visibility: Visibility
) => {
  const hiddenNodeIds = new Set<string>();
  const remainingNodes: Node[] = [];
  const nodeConnections: Record<string, string[]> = {};

  console.log("Nodes:", nodes);
  console.log("Edges:", edges);
  console.log("Visibility:", visibility);

  // Initialize nodeConnections for all nodes
  nodes.forEach((node) => {
    nodeConnections[node.id] = [];
  });

  // Filter nodes based on visibility
  nodes.forEach((node) => {
    if (
      (node.level === 1 && !visibility.group) ||
      (node.level === 2 && !visibility.role)
    ) {
      console.log(`Hiding node: ${node.id}, level: ${node.level}`);
      hiddenNodeIds.add(node.id);
    } else {
      remainingNodes.push(node);
    }
  });

  const tempEdges: Edge[] = [];
  const remainingEdges: Edge[] = [];

  // Populate node connections for all nodes
  edges.forEach((edge) => {
    const { sourceId, targetId } = edge;
    if (nodeConnections[sourceId]) {
      nodeConnections[sourceId].push(targetId);
    } else {
      nodeConnections[sourceId] = [targetId];
    }
    if (nodeConnections[targetId]) {
      nodeConnections[targetId].push(sourceId);
    } else {
      nodeConnections[targetId] = [sourceId];
    }

    if (!hiddenNodeIds.has(sourceId) && !hiddenNodeIds.has(targetId)) {
      remainingEdges.push(edge);
    }
  });

  console.log("Node connections:", nodeConnections);

  // Iterate through nodeConnections to create temporary edges for hidden nodes
  hiddenNodeIds.forEach((hiddenId) => {
    const neighbors = nodeConnections[hiddenId];
    if (neighbors && neighbors.length > 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < neighbors.length - 1; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < neighbors.length; j++) {
          const sourceId = neighbors[i];
          const targetId = neighbors[j];
          // Only create the edge if both source and target are not hidden
          if (!hiddenNodeIds.has(sourceId) && !hiddenNodeIds.has(targetId)) {
            const newEdge: Edge = {
              sourceId,
              targetId,
              properties: {}, // Add appropriate properties if needed
            };
            console.log(
              `Creating new edge from hidden node ${hiddenId}:`,
              newEdge
            );
            tempEdges.push(newEdge);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });


  return {
    nodes: remainingNodes,
    edges: [...remainingEdges, ...tempEdges],
  };
};

I am using the function above to make new edges, and later transform to show the various nodes
how i am handling visibility:
const handleVisibilityChange = (event) => {
    const { name, checked } = event.target;
    setVisibility((prevVisibility) => {
      const newVisibility = { ...prevVisibility, [name]: checked };
      if (name === "all") {
        newVisibility.group = checked;
        newVisibility.role = checked;
      } else {
        newVisibility.all = newVisibility.group && newVisibility.role;
      }
      return newVisibility;
    });
    setShouldFetch(true);
  };

const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState({
    all: true,
    group: true,
    role: true,
  });

group is level 1 and role is level 2
const { edges: filteredEdges } = filterNodesAndCreateEdges(
          nodeData,
          edgeData,
          visibility
        );


